# C programing How do i get a specific line of strings from a text file?

Tags: c, file

I've been tasked to create a program that will input a number, and the program will then open a file and retrieve the string on that given sentence. Here is the text file i am working with.

```
billy
bob
james
peter
mike
kieran
obidiah
scarlett
john
chloe
sarah
bob
leon
david
andrew
james
shawn
hannah
peter
phoebe
chris
john
mark
meg
```

Now, i decided it was easier to get a name, get a count value and reverse engineer it from there, however i am completely stuck on how to do it, can anyone help?

```
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int count = 1;

    char wd[20], word[20];

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("Names.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("given file doesn't exist");
        getch();
    } else {
        printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%s", word);
        fscanf(fp, "%s", wd);
        while (!feof(fp)) {
            if (strcmp(word, wd) == 0) {
                printf("%s found in the file. the given word is the %d word in the file", word, count);
                count = 0;
                break;
            } else {
                fscanf(fp, "%s", wd);
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count != 0) {
            printf("given word is not found in the file");
        }
        getch();
    }
}
```

This is the name to line code, I would like the count to name code.

Comment: You said that you are stuck in it, but what is the problem to solve? Which would be the specific question?

Comment: "input a number, and the program will then open a file and retrieve the string on that given sentence." Why are you asking for a name then? You're supposed to ask for a number according to your description.

Comment: You are suppoed to get a word on a specific sentence? Do you mean a specific line? An approach would be to first write a program that gets a specific line, say the 5th line, then generalize it to get the nth line. Use a while loop, but please don't use `while (!feof(fp))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fgets()` reads a line from a file, so if you need the nth line (and you're confident you know the maximum length of a line in your file) just call `fgets()` n times. The way you decided was easier is not easier, and doesn't seem to address the requested task.

Reading the line number from the command line so as to not quite meet the specifications of your homework, this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 1024


/*  Parse the command line arguments  */

int parse_cmd_line(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    /*  Check we have a single argument  */

    if ( argc != 2 ) {
        printf("You must enter a single integral argument.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    /*  Check that argument is an integer greater than zero  */

    char * endptr;
    int fline = strtol(argv[1], &endptr, 10);
    if ( *endptr || fline < 1 ) {
        printf("You must enter a positive non-zero integral argument.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return fline;
}


/*  Trim trailing whitespace from a string  */

char * trim_trailing(char * buffer) {
    int idx = strlen(buffer) - 1;
    while ( idx >= 0 && isspace(buffer[idx]) ) {
        buffer[idx--] = 0;
    }
    return buffer;
}


/*  Main function  */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fline = parse_cmd_line(argc, argv);

    FILE * infile = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if ( !infile ) {
        perror("Couldn't open data.txt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int count = fline;
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];

    while ( count-- > 0 ) {
        if ( fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE, infile) == NULL ) {
            printf("There aren't that many lines in the file.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    fclose(infile);

    printf("Line %d contains '%s'\n", fline, trim_trailing(buffer));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

will output, with your data file:

```
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$ ./fileline 1
Line 1 contains 'billy'
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$ ./fileline 7
Line 7 contains 'obidiah'
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$ ./fileline 24
Line 24 contains 'meg'
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$ ./fileline 25
There aren't that many lines in the file.
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$
```